# Group by a specific number and receive the sum in other columns using the group number

Tags: r

Inserting the data frame

```
data.frame(stocknum = c(1,1,2,2), text = c(1,1,1,0), final = c(0,0,1,0))
```

How is it possible to calculate the sum of every column (text, final) group by every stocknum value?

Expected result:

```
data.frame(stocknum_uni = c(1,2), text_sum = c(2,1), final_sum = c(0,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
res <- df %>% group_by(stocknum) %>%
  summarise_all(sum)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  stocknum  text final
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1        1     2     0
2        2     1     1
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(stocknum = c(1,1,2,2), text = c(1,1,1,0), final = c(0,0,1,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ stocknum, df, sum)
```

-output

```
#   stocknum text final
#1        1    2     0
#2        2    1     1
```

---

Or with `dplyr` using `across` from the newer version

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(stocknum) %>%
   summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  stocknum  text final
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1        1     2     0
#2        2     1     1
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(stocknum = c(1,1,2,2), text = c(1,1,1,0), final = c(0,0,1,0))
```